# How to compress json response in Laravel cause of multiple attribute appended?

Tags: laravel

Sir, I'm working on multiple attribute append in Laravel7. Below is example code in MainModel.

```
class MainModel extends Model
....
protected $appends = ['appendtomodeloneattribute','appendtomodeltwoattribute','appendtomodelthreeattribute'];
```

Once I try to do ajax request to query some on MainModel, for example.

```
$mainmodeldatas = MainModel::get();
return response()->json($mainmodeldatas);
```

I can get response because too big data. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Use [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination).

Comment: Hi Tpojka, is it capable for json? May I have more details, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can benefit from [laravel api collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#pagination).

Pagination with api collection. For example 20 records in each page.

```
return new mainModelCollection(MainModel::paginate(20));
```